# Realm throw catch swift 2.0

Tags: swift2, realm

does anyone know the syntax for the try-catch of the following realm function is?

```
realm.write() {
  realm.add(whatever)
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> call can throw but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not
>   handled

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I imagine realm.write() can throw an exception. In Swift 2 you handle exceptions with do/catch and try.

I suspect that you should do something like this:

```
do {
   try realm.write() {
      realm.add(whatever)
   }
} catch {
    print("Something went wrong!")
}
```

If realm.write() throws an exception, print statement will be invoked immediately.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like an NSError gets thrown. See the [Swift 2.0 source](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift-swift2.0/Realm.swift#L108)

Adding on to @tgebarowski's answer:

```
do {
    try self.realm.write {
        realm.add(whatever)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Something went wrong!")
    // use the error object such as error.localizedDescription
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(whatever)
}
```

Comment: I see that is some Realm docs but I don't see why they would make all there functions throw if they never intend them to fail. `try!` seems risky no?